# 'Visual Composer' plugin is outputting weird image links

Tags: wordpress

Morning everyone, i'm having a super weird issue with my recent wordpress migration. I moved the (working) site to another webspace and i'm slowly running out of ideas (jk, already ran out).

Issue: After the migration, the plugin Visual Composer is outputting nonsense image links to the frontend that look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsj8G.png instead of the uploaded images url. Result: No images are showing on the frontend.

This issue only happens when i use the single image block provided by VC itself. Inputting an image the wordpress way, inside of a text block, works.

What could be the reason for this? i'm super thankful for any advice since i'm not a programmer.

I have already tried:

- Enabling wp debug, not getting any errors
- Installing different versions of Visual Composer, multiple times
- Reinstalling Wordpress, multiple times
- disabling all plugins
- completely reinstalling and reuploading everything from scratch
- different php versions

Answer (score 0):

As I saw in your screenshot with the `src` attribute of your image and it has `data-src` attribute also, I think that it's because the new site (or maybe the new hosting) is using lazy load which will update all images source of the site to the lazy load image for better performance.

Lazy load images mean that the image won't load at the beginning, when you start to scroll down to each section, the images of this section will be loaded. In this way, the site will be optimized and won't load many resources at the beginning.

I think you can:

- Check if there is any cache plugin installed, try to deactivate this plugin.
- Check with the hosting provider if there is any cache setting installed, try to deactivate this setting also.
- See if the image is working in the backend or not, if it's still loaded in the backend, I'm pretty sure that it's the cache issue. If it doesn't load in the backend, I think there is something wrong with your theme source code.
- Compare the hosting environment, especially the PHP version of the old and new site to see if there is any differences.

Comment: Hello and thanks for the reply! There is no cache plugin enabled, same for the hosting settings. The image was indeed showing up in the backend, but the frontend was showing up the weird links.

I've solved it by using the "external" image link option in the single image settings, there was no way to make it work the intended way. same php settings btw.